# How can I stop a While loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I wrote a `while loop` in a function, but don't know how to stop it. When it doesn't meet its final condition, the loop just go for ever. How can I stop it?

```
def determine_period(universe_array):
    period=0
    tmp=universe_array
    while True:
        tmp=apply_rules(tmp)#aplly_rules is a another function
        period+=1
        if numpy.array_equal(tmp,universe_array) is True:
            break    #i want the loop to stop and return 0 if the 
                     #period is bigger than 12
    if period>12:  #i wrote this line to stop it..but seems it 
                   #doesnt work....help..
        return 0
    else:   
        return period
```

Comment: the problem is in your question.  "when it doesnt meet its final condition..".  You are not testing for a final condition, you are saying "while true:".  True will always be True.

Comment: thanks for your comment,i just about half known about while loop..so dont really know how to ask a good question..

Comment: The problem here was caused by a typo - incorrect indentation - as demonstrated by the top/accepted answer. Another editor promptly came along and "fixed" the indentation, ruining the example and making the code functionally identical to the code in the answer, such that the question made no sense. I have fixed that; but the question should still be closed and deleted, as it **does not address the subject matter being asked about** and is **actively misleading**. It should originally have either been closed due to the typo, or routed to some general question about indentation.

Comment: We have a canonical now that talks about the purpose of indentation in Python, but a) it's oriented towards resolving `IndentationError` rather than invalid logic; b) OP seems to have understood the necessary principles at the time; c) if dupe-hammered, this would be utterly nonsensical as a signpost.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

just indent your code correctly:

```
def determine_period(universe_array):
    period=0
    tmp=universe_array
    while True:
        tmp=apply_rules(tmp)#aplly_rules is a another function
        period+=1
        if numpy.array_equal(tmp,universe_array) is True:
            return period
        if period>12:  #i wrote this line to stop it..but seems its doesnt work....help..
            return 0
        else:   
            return period
```

You need to understand that the `break` statement in your example will exit the infinite loop you've created with `while True`. So when the break condition is True, the program will quit the infinite loop and continue to the next indented block. Since there is no following block in your code, the function ends and don't return anything. So I've fixed your code by replacing the `break` statement by a `return` statement.

Following your idea to use an infinite loop, this is the best way to write it:

```
def determine_period(universe_array):
    period=0
    tmp=universe_array
    while True:
        tmp=apply_rules(tmp)#aplly_rules is a another function
        period+=1
        if numpy.array_equal(tmp,universe_array) is True:
            break
        if period>12:  #i wrote this line to stop it..but seems its doesnt work....help..
            period = 0
            break

    return period
```

Comment: yes, because you had another bug in your code: a break statement which was preventing your function to return something. I removed it now.

Comment: but it always return 0 now...thanks alot though~~~u r so nice

Comment: don't check if something() is True: Check the object direct like in "if numpy.array_equal(tmp,universe_array):"

Answer (score 7):

```
def determine_period(universe_array):
    period=0
    tmp=universe_array
    while period<12:
        tmp=apply_rules(tmp)#aplly_rules is a another function
        if numpy.array_equal(tmp,universe_array) is True:
            break 
        period+=1

    return period
```

Comment: +1 but would be nice to point out what+why, "while true" eeek

Comment: Joel code loop until period is 12 than stop looping and return period... it,s normal... Joel code isn't what you want

Comment: This is closer.  And yes, I do expect him to think for himself some as well.

Comment: Be careful: this still won't return what you want if the if condition isn't true.  I'm leaving that last point as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn,i cant stop myself to say you are really a good teacher!love this formu,because it has so many teachers like you.

Answer (score 2):

The `is` operator in Python probably doesn't do what you expect. Instead of this:

```
    if numpy.array_equal(tmp,universe_array) is True:
        break
```

I would write it like this:

```
    if numpy.array_equal(tmp,universe_array):
        break
```

The `is` operator tests object identity, which is something quite different from equality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of example code from Charles Severance's "python or everybody" about writing while True loops:

```py
while True:
    line = input('> ')
    if line == 'done':
        break
    print(line)
print('Done!')
```

This helped me with my problem!

Comment: Hi @tkirk1222, welcome to Stack Overflow! When answering questions, please try to keep your answers as general and on topic as possible and offer up more of an explanation. In this case, the question asks about stopping a `while True` loop, so you should explain the part of your code that does that (the `break` statement). The other stuff may be misleading to someone else without an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I would do it using a for loop as shown below :

```
def determine_period(universe_array):
    tmp = universe_array
    for period in xrange(1, 13):
        tmp = apply_rules(tmp)
        if numpy.array_equal(tmp, universe_array):
            return period
    return 0
```