# Pause an infinite while loop with a single keypress

Tags: python, loops, ubuntu, while-loop, infinite

I'm new to python and I have been trying to find a simple way to pause an operating while-loop, making it possible to start it again from where it was paused. I have searched on Google for help and tips, but everything I find seems very complex. Is there a simple way to do this?

I've read that you can use termios and tkinter.

I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368545/how-can-i-stop-a-while-loop   
this is possible duplicate question, take a look

Comment: @doniyor: Pausing is not quite the same as stopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple tkinter program that runs in an infinite loop. Pressing <kbd>space</kbd> pauses/unpauses it, and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> quits.

Note: The following is for Python 2.x, if you're using Python 3, change `Tkinter` in the first line to `tkinter` (lower case t).

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class MyLoop():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.running = True
        self.aboutToQuit = False
        self.root = root
        self.someVar = 0
        self.root.bind("<space>", self.switch)
        self.root.bind("<Escape>", self.exit) 

        while not self.aboutToQuit:
            self.root.update() # always process new events

            if self.running:
                # do stuff
                self.someVar += 1
                print(self.someVar)
                time.sleep(.1)

            else: # If paused, don't do anything
                time.sleep(.1)

    def switch(self, event):
        print(['Unpausing','Pausing'][self.running])
        self.running = not(self.running)

    def exit(self, event):
        self.aboutToQuit = True
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw() # don't show the tkinter window
    MyLoop(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is a possible output, where I manually paused and unpaused the program twice before I quit.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Pausing
Unpausing
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
Pausing
Unpausing
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't about how to do it with a single keypress, but to resume and pause a while loop you can use `generator functions`, see the example below:

```
i=-1
def infi():
   global i
   while i<99999999:
       i+=1
       yield i

a=iter(infi())

for x in range(6):
    print(next(a))
#loop paused at 5     
print('now it wil start from start 6')

for x in range(11):
    print(next(a))
```

**output:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
now it wil start from start 6
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! The thing is just i want to be able to pause it at any given time as it is looping.

Comment: @user1488138 this is what `generator function` do, they can pause their execution and can start their execution where they left.

Comment: @Ashwini: This doesn't seem to do what OP asked for at all. How can the user pause the process?

Comment: okey, sorry for my stupid questions^^ would it be possible with a similar function make it so that i could pause it at a random time as it actually is running? Without having a specific place it should pause and resume?

Answer (score 0):

dude it's a while loop... don't run it in a while loop, that will block up the CPU, just try using timers...

Here is a python 3 example of getting input from a window that is not displayed, tested on OSX, Linux Ubuntu and Windows 8

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 'running'
        self.cnt = 0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.update_clock()
        self.root.bind("<Key>", self.key)
        self.root.geometry('1x1+9000+9000')
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_clock(self):
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.root.after(100, self.update_clock)
        self.root.focus_set()
        if(self.state == 'running'):
            self.cnt = self.cnt + 1
        if(self.cnt <= 100):
            print('state: ',self.state,' count:',self.cnt,'%')
        else:
            exit()

    def key(self,event):
        self.root.focus_force()
        if(event.keysym == 'Escape'):
            self.state = 'paused'
        elif(event.keysym == 'space'):
            self.state = 'running'
        print("pressed", repr(event.keysym))
        print("state",self.state)
app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

You can thank @saranyan for this...

Comment: Oh btw you should probably self.root.focus_set() inside update_clock method, and to save the number have count or data as another var declared in __init__, but updated only if(self.state == 'paused'):

Answer (score 0):

I searched forever for this solution, but it turned out to be really simple.  I'm pretty the select module only works on Unix systems, but it made things really easy.

```
import sys
import select
inputSrc = [sys.stdin]

while True:

    # Do important stuff

    # Check if a key was pressed and if so, process input
    keypress = select.select(inputSrc, [], [], 0)[0]
    while keypress:
        for src in keypress:
            line = src.readline()
            if not line:
                inputSrc.remove(src)
            else:
                # The "enter" key prints out a menu
                if line == "\n":
                    print "Test Paused\nOptions: [0]: Quit  [any other key]: Resume"
                elif line.rstrip() == "0":
                    exit(0)
                elif len(line) >= 1: #any other key
                    print "Resuming..."
                    keypress = None
```