# Relatively new to programming and can't figure out how to exit the magic8ball function back to the gamer function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a magic 8 ball program, however, I cannot figure out how to return from the magic 8 ball function to the gamer function. `

```
def gamer():
choice = int(input("What game do you want to play? \n[1]Magic 8 Ball  \n[2]Dice?\n[3]Exit \n"))
if choice == 1:
    def magic8ball():
        import random
        print("\nWelcome to the Magic 8 Ball Program. Input your question and hit enter for the 8 ball to respond")
        print("What is your question?")

        userinput = input()
        choices = ["It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Without a doubt", "Yes definitely", "You may rely on it", "As I see it, yes", 
        "Most likely", "Outlook good", "Yes", 'Signs point to yes', "Reply hazy try again", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now",
        "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Dont count on it", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not good", 'Very doubful']
        if userinput != "exit" or "EXIT" or "Exit":
            print(random.choice(choices))
        if userinput == "exit" or "Exit" or "EXIT":
            #Where I need help
    magic8ball()
    while True:
        magic8ball()
        continue`
```

Comment: please fix the indentation

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop a While loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368545/how-can-i-stop-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You must return some information to the calling context, so that the loop can be broken. You could do sth like this:

```
def magic8ball():
    # ....
    if userinput.lower() == "exit":
        return True
while True:
    if magic8ball():
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than signal the caller, I'd make `magic8ball()` implement it's own loop, returning to the caller's loop when finished:

```
import random

ANSWERS = [
    "It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Without a doubt", "Yes definitely",
    "You may rely on it", "As I see it, yes", "Most likely", "Outlook good",
    "Yes", "Signs point to yes", "Reply hazy try again", "Ask again later",
    "Better not tell you now", "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again",
    "Don't count on it", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not good", 'Very doubtful'
]

def magic8ball():

    print("\nWelcome to the Magic 8 Ball Program.")
    print("Type your question and hit enter for the Magic 8 ball to respond.")

    while True:
        print("What is your question?")

        userinput = input("> ")

        if userinput.lower() == "exit":
            return

        print(random.choice(ANSWERS))

def gamer():
    while True:
        print("What game do you want to play?\n[1]Magic 8 Ball\n[2]Dice\n[3]Exit")

        choice = int(input("> "))

        if choice == 1:
            magic8ball()
        elif choice == 2:
            pass
        elif choice == 3:
            return

gamer()
```