# How to stop this loop after the correct execution of command in python

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I am trying build this thing where: if you type wrong answer the program will run again and if you write correct one it should stop but even after writing correct statement it is not stopping

```
EvenOdd = 1

def choosegame():
    while True:
        global gname
        gname = input("\nWhich game would you like to play?\n    1.Even&Odd\n         OR         \n    2.Three lines\n\tType the number of the game to start\n>>>")
        if "1" or "Even&Odd" or "even&odd" or "evenodd" or "even" or "odd" in gname:
            gname = EvenOdd
            print("odd even game passed")
            break
        elif "2" or "Three" or "three" or "Lines" or "lines" in gname:
            print("threeline game passes")
            break
        else:
            print("wrong word")
    return choosegame
choosegame()
```

Comment: It's `if gname == "1" or gname == "Even&Odd"` etc. or `if gname in ["1","Even&Odd","even&odd"....]` etc.

Comment: the code still stays in infinite loop

Comment: Hi! Check this issue's solution out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368545/how-can-i-stop-a-while-loop

Comment: @KeshavSharma Well yes, as you return the function itself `return choosegame` it starts over.

Answer (score 2):

you are not checking the condition of the variable

try this

```
EvenOdd = 1

def choosegame():
    while True:

        gname = input("\nWhich game would you like to play?\n    1.Even&Odd\n         OR         \n    2.Three lines\n\tType the number of the game to start\n>>>")
        if gname in ["1", "Even&Odd", "even&odd", "evenodd", "even", "odd"]:
            gname = EvenOdd
            print("odd even game passed")
            break
        elif gname in ["2", "Three", "three", "Lines", "lines"]:
            print("threeline game passed")
            break
        else:
            print("wrong word")
    return gname

choosegame()
```

Answer (score 0):

`if "1" or "Even&Odd" or "even&odd" or "evenodd" or "even" or "odd" in gname:`

This particular line does not behave like you intend it to. This will always evaluate to true because `if "1"` does not compare values but rather just checks if the value exists or not.

You can better understand this by the snippet below:

```py
my_variable = None

if my_variable:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

This will print "No" when `my_variable` is None but will print "Yes" if `my_variable` has any type of value.

So you should define explicit checks i.e. `if gname == "1" or gname == "even"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is inaccurate where it says

```
if "1" or "Even&Odd" or "even&odd" or "evenodd" or "even" or "odd" in gname:
```

because the conditions are ("1"), ("Even&Odd"), ... and ("odd" in gname). The conditions which are just strings evaulate to True because any non-empty string is True.

The correct line would be:

```
if gname in ["1", "Even&Odd", "even&odd", "evenodd", "even", "odd"]:
```

because this checks if the entered gname is in the list of valid values.