How to get next user input in python for while loop?
I am currently in school taking a python course in this lab it is asking me to create a loop that outputs the users input into a sentence until user enters quit
Ex: If the input is:
apples 5
shoes 2
quit 0

the output is:
Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.
Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away.

my code is:
your_input = input() #input string and int 
string_value = your_input.split()
str_value = string_value[0]
int_value = string_value[1]

while 'quit' not in your_input:
    print("Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.".format(int_value,str_value))
    your_input = input()
    break

Output:
Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.

when it should be:
Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.
Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away.

using the input:
apples 5
shoes 2
quit 0


You should look up what break does.

Everything that should be done on each iteration should be inside your loop.  If it's not in the loop, then it will only be executed once.

when I move the variable assignments into loop i get an infinite loop

We have a galaxy's worth of duplicates for this type of question. Most of them are poor quality, but see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68153775

try something like this,
your_input = input() #input string and int 
string_value = your_input.split() 
str_value = string_value[0] 
int_value = string_value[1]

while 'quit' not in your_input:
    print("Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.".format(int_value,str_value))
    your_input = input()
    string_value = your_input.split() 
    str_value = string_value[0] 
    int_value = string_value[1]

the issue with your current code is that you don't need break as you already have a terminating condition in while statement, then you need to split your input in every iteration of loop
